# nx nrwl mono repo doesn't use build results

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl

I've had doubt about if nx is helping with build effort and wanted to prove it.

I've created 4 packages, each different build engine. I made one the package to have a plugin to change the build result different than the actual `.ts` file to confirm if the actual file is used or the dist folder's result.

then checked the dist folder, and sadly none of the dist packages, used the result of dist folder.

did I configure anything wrong?

### how I tested it

I created 4 packages and 1 app:

[image: 4 packages folder structure]

all packages have dependency on rollup

[image]

then [configured roll up to use a replace string plugin](https://github.com/mhamri/Bundling-Issues-in-Nx/blob/main/packages/is-rollup/rollup.config.js)

```js
module.exports =  (config, options)=>{
  return {

    ...config,
    plugins:[
      ...config.plugins,
      {
        name: '@rollup/plugin-replace',
        transform: (x)=>{
          console.log(x);
          return x.replace(/ __BuildDate__/, new Date()); 
        }
      }
    ]
  }

};
```

then I built everything and looked at the dist folder's result

rollup successfully built correctly

[image]

but all other packages and app didn't

### esbuild:

[image]

### vite:

[image]

and here is the repo:

https://github.com/mhamri/Bundling-Issues-in-Nx